# How can I reference for a two cameras on prefab through script?

Tags: unity, c#

I have this script for controlling the cameras :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamerasViewSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Camera> cameras = new List<Camera>();
    public string currentViewMode;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (cameras[0].enabled)
        {
            currentViewMode = "Third Person";
        }
        else
        {
            currentViewMode = "First View";
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
        {
            cameras[0].enabled = !cameras[0].enabled;
            cameras[1].enabled = !cameras[1].enabled;

            if (cameras[0].enabled)
            {
                currentViewMode = "Third Person";
            }
            else
            {
                currentViewMode = "First View";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the Assets, I have a prefab with two children's cameras that I want to use in this script.

In this screenshot to show what I mean, I dragged the prefab name Platform to the hierarchy to show where the cameras are. The script is on the object name Cameras Switch.

How do I get these two cameras from the prefab and using them in the script?

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using the Platform prefab with this script but the problem is when I'm starting the game the CamerasViewSwitch script is missing the two cameras I'm not to get/find them.

[image: Platform usage]

Comment: Can I clarify... The two cameras are children of the `Platform` object _in the prefab_? If you double-click the prefab to load it into the scene view, are the cameras wired up correctly?

Comment: @Basic You right. For now I solved it by add a public variable for the platform in the cameras switch script : public GameObject platformPrefab; then in the Start var cams = platformPrefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Camera>(); then I can use this array cams or assign the cams to the List cameras but this way it's working. Is that a good way to do it ?

Comment: It depends... It'll work but it's not ideal if anyone else might ever edit that prefab. It's not intuitive that (say) rearranging some cameras in a prefab would fundamentally change/break how the game plays. I would've thought what you're trying should've worked but I haven't done it myself. I'll give it a test later and see if I can reproduce/resolve after work

Comment: @Basic Thank you very much. I will wait for your answer.

Comment: @Basic Another options is using maybe a cinemachine camera/s for that.  The reason the two cameras are children of the platform prefab is so they will move with the platform. but maybe using cinemachine camera/s will be better or using one camera that will not be child of the platform and make the camera by script to follow the platform and only to change the camera position each time for third person/first person views switch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for how to programmatically get the `Camera` objects that are not children of the `GameObject` your script is on?

If so, you'll need a way to determine specifically which object to look under, but if you can reliably assume there will only be 1 `GameObject` in the scene with the name "Platform", then something like this:

```
public GameObject Platform;
private Camera FirstPersonCamera;
private Camera ThirdPersonCamera;
private void Start()
{
    Platform = Platform ?? GameObject.Find("Platform");
    var cameras = Platform.GetComponentsInChildren<Camera>();
    FirstPersonCamera = cameras.FirstOrDefault(c => c.name == "First Person View Camera");
    ThirdPersonCamera = cameras.FirstOrDefault(c => c.name == "Third Person View Camera");
}
```

I've created variables to hold each camera so that you only have to do a lookup once in `Start()` and also so you can more reliably know which camera is which instead of relying on the order of the `Camera`s as children of "Capsule" (if you want to be even more confident, create Tags like "[1st|3rd] Person Camera" or something, assign them to the appropriate `Camera`s in the Prefab, and do a lookup on the Tag instead of the Name).

If you can't assume that there will only ever be 1 `GameObject` in the scene called "Platform", then you'll have to figure out how to get the reference of the correct one.

**EDIT:** This also assumes that the "Platform" prefab exists in the scene when `Start()` is executed (when the `GameObject` the script is on becomes active in the scene). If that is not the case, you'll have to create a function to assign the cameras after "Platform" is placed in the scene.